# jQuery cut link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

Here is `html`:

```
<a href="http://site.com/any/different/folders/picture_name.jpg">Go and win</a>
<a href="http://site.com/not/similar/links/some_other_name.png">Go and win</a>
```

How to cut all the data from `a href`, except `picture_name.jpg`? There can be any length of the link, we must take just the value from last `/` to last `"`

And anybody does know the shortest way to compare, if `alt` and `title` of current link are equal?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your second question...`alt` isn't a valid attribute on `<a>`, do you mean on an `<img>` tag somewhere?

Comment: emm sorry, thats the part of other question, but it too small so I'm asked here. Using alt for images, not for links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to actually change the `href` to `picture_name.jpg` and `some_other_name.png` respectively, you can pass a function to [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and use [`.lastIndexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastIndexOf.asp)/[`.substring()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp), like this:

```
$("a").attr('href', function(i, href) {
  return href.substring(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
});
```

[You can view/play with a quick demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/MCULz/)

---

Alternatively if you're using a `.each()` you can get/use the value like this:

```
$("a").each(function() {
  var new_href = this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  //use it, e.g.: alert(new_href);
});​
```

[You can see a demo of that here](http://jsfiddle.net/MCULz/1/)

Comment: I want to throw picture_name.jpg into new variable. var link = ? Can you update?

Comment: @Happy - Can you clarify a bit? Each link would be a different variable, so where do you want this variable to go? Are you doing one link at a time or...?

Comment: `var links = [];
$("a").attr('href', function(i, href) {
  links[] = href.substring(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
});`

Comment: var link = $(this).attr('href', function(i, href) {return href.substring(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

Comment: @Happy - Updated the answer to show a quick way to do that :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var hrefs = $("a").map( function() {
  return this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
})
```

will return an array:

```
["picture_name.jpg", "some_other_name.png"]
```

Well, and the other question...

> And anybody does know the shortest way to compare, if `alt` and `title` of current link are equal?

Sure, just compare them

```
var currentLink = $("a")[0]; // whatever

if (currentLink.alt == currentLink.title) {
  // some action
} else {
  // some other action
}
```

Comment: The second part of the answer wouldn't ever evaluate to true, `currentLink.alt` would always be undefined, since it's not a valid property/attribute. Short demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/vQPQa/

Answer (score 2):

Once you grab the a element with getElementsByTagName or getElementById:

```
var parts = element.href.split('/')
last_part = parts[parts.length-1]
```

Comment: `parts.pop()` will work too, or `split('/').pop()` for just the last part. don't forget your semi-colons :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = $("#link");
var link = a.href;
alert( link.substr(0, link.lastIndexOf("/")+1) );
alert(a.href == a.title);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a regular expression:

`var url = element.href.match(/([^/]*)$/)[1];`